# add zero after single number if needed

Tags: php, laravel

i want to add zero after number if number is single

e.g `$a = 2` then `20`
if `$a = 20` then `20`
if `$a = 12` then '12'

like this. I some things but it didn't work for me.
How to do it ?

Comment: Simple if condition will help. If(number > 10)...else{...}

Comment: `sprintf("%0-2s", $a)`

Comment: No `if` tests required, and no mathematical operations required, so not that heavy.... not intuitive what it's doing though, so I wouldn't recommend it... but just showing an alternative approach

Comment: @tilz0R not so sure about the if and math being faster. My test shows that it's quite significantly slower. Your method: https://3v4l.org/Ebtr4/perf#output my method: https://3v4l.org/qmH4t/perf#output your method takes almost twice as long.

Comment: @Mark your "answer" is actually the fastest. https://3v4l.org/7qnN0/perf#output

Comment: @Andreas - I didn't think it would be bad performance; but certainly wouldn't have expected it to be measurably faster than `str_pad()`... though it's still not intuitive.... and performancce might vary with double digit values for $a

Comment: @Mark that can be true. I was just interested in seeing if his claims that an if and math is faster. It seems false on the small scale test.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if`-statements:

```
if ($a < 10) $a *= 10;
```

Comment: Question states `if 2 then make it 20` that is not add 10. This comment was to @tilzOR

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be too hard.

```
$number = intval($number)
if ($number > 0 && $number < 10) {
    $number *= 10;
}
```

Comment: Based on the comment above I do not find this method appropriate. It's quite slower than str_pad and sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_pad to pad with zeros.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
Echo str_pad($a, 2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```